# Problemas com Chart's no JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, jasper

Tenho que fazer um relatório que possua dois gráficos de pizza, o que acontece é que 
meu primeiro chart aparece sem problemas, o segundo não, e já fiz a verificação se as listas, que são enviadas via parâmetro, e as mesmas estão populadas.

```
parametros.put("LIST_GRAFICO_RECEITAS", listaGraficoReceitas);
parametros.put("LIST_GRAFICO_DESPESAS", listaGraficoDespesas);
```

Porém só um dos chart's é exibido. Alguém já passou por isso?

[image: Este é meu jrxml]

[image: Devia ter outro chart ao lado]

Esta é a minha conexão do chart(este refere-se ao gráfico de receita) com o relatório:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{LIST_GRAFICO_RECEITAS})
```

O mesmo para o outro chart(gráfico de despesas):

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{LIST_GRAFICO_DESPESAS})
```

Comment: Galera, quem puder responder, já tentei tudo o que me cabia, até mesmo sub-relatórios uma vez que as duas listas citadas a cima são do mesmo tipo. Fico no aguardo. Abraço.